# C++ class with const pointer as data member, destructor and no default constructor

Tags: c++

I came across this C++ code. What are the issues in it? I can see that copy and assignment will be an issue, because a pointer is used as data member.

```
class Vehicle
{
    char const* type;
public:
    Vehicle(char const* tt) : type(tt) {}
    char const* getType() const
    {
        return type;
    }
    ~Vehicle()
    {
        delete type;
    }
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Whoever even came up with this is in dire need of a good C++ book. And the last sentence of yours suggests you are, too.

Comment: `delete type;` I mistrust this. The class isn't self-contained, aka it isn't well designed and should be eradicated.

Comment: `Vehicle v("fasfsafasf");` crash on exit

Answer (score 2):

A trivial bit of refactoring makes this class much more stable, at the expense of a string copy:

```
class Vehicle
{
    std::string type;
public:
    Vehicle(char const* tt) : type(tt) {}
    char const* getType() const
    {
        return type.c_str();
    }
};
```

Then I'd suggest that you change the return type of `getType()` to a `const std::string&`:

```
const std::string& getType() const
{
    return type;
}
```

At least then you don't need to worry about the returned pointer of a `getType` type being *invalidated* if the `type` member is changed.